# Cover a uicontrol with a uipanel

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, uicontrol

In Matlab R2014a I want to create a `uicontrol` that will be partially covered by a `uipanel`.

If I run the following function:

```
function test()
h = figure;
set(h, 'Position', [100, 100, 500, 300]);
mainPanel = uipanel(                     ...
  'Parent'         , h                 , ...
  'Units'          , 'pixels'          , ...
  'Position'       , [10, 10, 300, 500], ...
  'BackgroundColor', [0.6, 0.6, 0.6]     ...
  );
uicontrol(                        ...
  'Parent'  , mainPanel         , ...
  'Units'   , 'pixels'          , ...
  'Style'   , 'popupmenu'       , ...
  'String'  , {'S1', 'S2', 'S3'}, ...
  'Position', [100, 200, 200, 20] ...
  );
topPanel = uipanel(                        ...
  'Parent'         , mainPanel           , ...
  'Units'          , 'pixels'            , ...
  'Position'       , [150, 160, 100, 100], ...
  'BackgroundColor', [0.9, 0.2, 0.1]       ...
  );
end
```

I obtain the following figure:

[image: Example]

Even if I draw the red panel after the `uicontrol` and with the same parent, it does not cover the control.

Instead, I want to draw a panel that covers all existing graphics. The result that I want to obtain is the following one:

[image]

How can I create a panel that covers existing controls (and other panels) that appear in the figure?

Of course this is only a test function for showing the problem, my real problem is more complex and related to create a scrollable panel...

Comment: On R2016a I get a figure similar to the second image, from your code. Anyway, you can try `uistack(topPanel,'top')`

Comment: Unfortunately uistack does not work...

Comment: OK, seems `uistack` changed its behaviour in R2041b. I think you need to re-order the children of `mainPanel`. For only two components you can simply do - `tmp = get(mainPanel,'Children'); set(mainPanel,'Children',flipud(tmp))`

Comment: After reading this- https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics_transition/why-are-some-components-missing-or-partially-obscured.html, I'm not sure my suggestion will work... Maybe you should define `topPanel` as a child of the popupmenu